# Bug in closing as duplicate?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

If you have a gold badge in a tag then you can immediately close as a duplicate any question that has that tag. So for example I have a gold badge in [general-relativity] and [newtonian-mechanics] and *should* be able to close as duplicates any questions tagged with these.

However I just VTC'd as duplicate the question [What would be gravity in one spatial dimension?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200346/what-would-be-gravity-in-one-spatial-dimension) and it didn't close. The question has the [general-relativity] tag, but it was added (before my VTC) by Qmechanic, so the question wasn't originally tagged with [general-relativity].

I also recently VTC'd as duplicate the question [What makes neutron heavier than a proton?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200330/) and it did immediately close even though it has neither the [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity) nor [newtonian-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics) tags. However I note that it did originally have the [newtonian-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics) tag but this was removed (before my VTC) by Qmechanic.

So it looks to me as if the immediate close as duplicate code looks at the tags the question originally had, and not any changes made after the question was posted.

Perhaps this is just to stop me randomly closing any question by editing the tags before voting to close :-)

Comment: [Is there anything to stop a Gold Tag person editing a tag in to close any question they want?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251851/271002)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a bug.
The gold badge privilege is described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) as follows.

> You can instantly close *as a duplicate* any question that was **originally** asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.

> You can instantly reopen any question *closed as a duplicate* that was **originally** asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.

> If a question has a tag where you have a gold badge, and it was part of the **original set of tags** applied to the question, you can mark it as a duplicate with a single vote.

> Likewise, if you have a gold tag badge in one of the **original tags** of something marked as a duplicate and feel a mistake was made, you can re-open it with a single vote and (optionally) mark it as a duplicate of another (theoretically better) question.

Comment: Ah, thanks. It's behaviour as intended then.